# Wordpress user login event

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to redirect user after login in his profile. I do:

```
function do_anything() {

    echo "<script>console.log( 'Hi: ' );</script>";
}
add_action('wp_login', 'do_anything');
```

But after user login console still empty. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine
but for sure set priority to your function and it's better to use die('working'); inside your function instead console.log();

add_action('wp_login', 'your_function', 10, 2); I'm using this and it's work fine for me.

Comment: The default priority is 10...no need to explicitly set it here.

Comment: I tried to add `10,2`. But same result. Maybe its not work becouse i create plugin to write my code? I gonna put my code in functions.php?